# What plugin for Photoshop can I use to remove camera-shake blur?

Tags: software, post-processing, photoshop, blur, camera-shake

What is the best anti blur plug-in for Photoshop image editor and how effective can it be without compromising with the image quality or increasing sharpness/noise?

I am especially interested in rectifying the camera shakes caused by slow shutter-speed.

Comment: This may sound just a bit snarky, but if you need to use a plug-in to remove blur from an image, why on earth would you be concerned about "compromising sharpness"?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9446/how-should-one-sharpen-differently-depending-on-the-target-usage-for-a-photo — Pradeep, does that cover what you're asking here, or are you looking for tools to remove motion or camera-shake blur, or to compensate for focus errors?

Comment: @stans- my mistake for not being clear,i meant i was worried about compromising with the image quality without any increase in noise.

Comment: @mattdm- yeah,plug-in to correct the camera blurred image due to slow shutter speed at low lightings.

Comment: @pradeep: Mistakes are fine, because the software here makes it easy to make things better. You can edit your own question to make it more clear, so you get higher-quality replies. You will probably also get better results if you punctuate and capitalize with some more care — nicely-done questions invite nicely-done answers.

Comment: related question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/how-postprocessing-can-help-in-improvingor-remove-slightly-blurred-photos

Comment: also see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/can-anyone-recommend-freeware-to-reduce-motion-blur-by-deconvolution

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using (and happy with) Topaz Labs products, then take a look at Topaz InFocus. In addition to being an excellent sharpening plug-in in general, it has a deblur tool that can recover directionally blurred images very well and make up somewhat for focus errors (always a bit of a gamble, since the plugin has no way of knowing what the intended point of focus might have been).

Answer (score 2):

Software can only attempt to rectify the issue after it's been recorded.  The ideal approach, if you're interested in becoming a better photographer, is to deal with the issue at it's source, meaning you should learn to shoot images that are not blurring in the first place.

If you are recording still life, there are many effective methods to photographing precisely sharp images with a slow-shutter speed.  I used to shoot sunsets with 20 second exposures.  Using a tripod, mirror-lock-up, and a remote, I never had any problems.

If you are hand-holding the camera, shooting an average focal length (around 35mm) you will most always get blurring of anything slower than 1/60 sec. exposure.

If you must shoot at these slower speeds, and are holding the camera, you will never get sharp results out of camera.  You will want to open up to a larger aperture, letting more light into the lens, thus decreasing your exposure time.  That means you can then use a faster shutter-speed which of course equals less blur.

If you are looking for an easy fix to avoid blur, just kick up the ISO and then increase your shutter speed.

The ISO designates the "speed" of the photographic sensor, which means you can increase the shutter-speed.  The result is added noise/grain as you go to higher ISOs.  However, increased ISO can be very effective in low-light situations where you must hold the camera and need sharp images.  The noise/grain is viewed as artistic enhancement by some, and problematic for others.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options; I have used Sharpener Pro from Nik Software with good results. Obviously I try to take a well-focused photo at the start, to avoid needing a plugin to reduce blur.

You can see more info about this plugin at the [official Sharpener Pro page.](http://www.niksoftware.com/sharpenerpro/usa/entry.php?)

Comment: i use topaz denoise 5.1.0 ,it has given me positive outcomes above my expectations.it has excellent data recovery and noise removal features.,my problem is with the blurs caused by the camera shakes due to slow shutter-speed .

Comment: Hi there! There's no need to 'sign' your answers here on photo-SE, and our community policy is not to include personal links within answers... I'd encourage you to put links to your Flickr photostream (or whatever you'd like to) in the 'About Me' section of your personal page...