# What algorithms and values does Lightroom use for sharpening for print and for screen?

Tags: printing, lightroom-3, display, sharpening

In the Lightroom exporting menu, there are options to sharpen for screen and print.

What are the differences between the two? And how does each setting actually sharpen the image? And finally what is the benefit of this feature over manually sharpening in the "develop" phase of the process?

---

Update:

After several comments I have decided to edit the question to clarify why I have asked it and why previous questions on similar topics have not answered it.

I am after the values it uses and how it defines these values when sharpening, so that if it is too much or too little I can replicate it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should one sharpen differently depending on the target usage for a photo?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9446/how-should-one-sharpen-differently-depending-on-the-target-usage-for-a-photo)

Comment: this is about the sharpening setting in Lightroom and requires more detail from an answer.

Comment: Why? Answers to the other question give (or should give) the explanation for why there are two different options and what the differences between them might be. For why you might prefer to do it as part of the export instead of in the middle of your workflow, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/why-should-my-last-post-processing-step-be-sharpening.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad question, or that the answers there are as complete as they might be — just that it really is the same question, and it's better to have answers all in one place rather than spread between duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't answer how it sharpens. It does answer what the difference is.

Comment: So are you really asking "what does sharpening do?" As in this question - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/unsharp-mask-what-do-the-parameters-do

Comment: No I know what sharpening does. I want to know how much it sharpens and what amounts of luminescence, radius and sharpening they use so they can be replicated and altered manually.

Comment: Okay, got it. Suggest editing the question to focus on asking about the algorithms and values that Lightroom uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the actual settings Lightroom uses I do not know and you may want to ask over on the [Adobe Lightroom Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/community/lightroom).

However I did come across [this bit of information](http://laurashoe.com/2011/08/21/sharpening-in-lightroom-part-one-overview-and-capture-sharpening/) and thought it might be useful to others if not yourself:

> Output Sharpening:  this is size and medium dependent, and is accomplished in the Print, Slideshow and Web modules, and in the Export dialog where you create jpeg and other copies.  A large print needs significantly more sharpening than a small image to be viewed on the web;  an image printed  on matte paper needs more sharpening than one on glossy paper because the ink soaks into the former.   Output sharpening takes into account size, resolution and medium.

Comment: I know your post was partly a quote so you may not know but How can the output sharpening take into account the size, resolution and medium if at export these values have not been defined. Such as paper/enlargement size?

Comment: @GraemeHutchison  You are right, I do not know. I would check the Adobe Forums for more detailed info.

Comment: I will have a look their if no answer is here in the next couple of days, I have given you +1 for your answer as it adds interesting details about the need for sharpening for enlargements.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - Hope any information helps. As for the Adobe Forums I have found them a great source of info for Adobe program specific information (and some non-program information). There are people that eat sleep and breath those programs (including Adobe Employees) that chime in on those forums.

Comment: In Lightroom when you export, all those things are known because it asks for ALL that info. Of course, you can lie to Lightroom and print it bigger or smaller ;)

Comment: If you do find the answer somewhere else, it'd be useful to provide it back here. I suspect, however, that the exact process and values used are internal-black-box-secret-sauce that the company doesn't share.