# How do I recreate the colours and what seems to be a filter on the image

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, airplanes

I found this photo on a flickr page and was wondering how to create those colours and what seems to be some kind of coloured filter added on top.

Subject images; https://flic.kr/p/tpEh5E
https://flic.kr/p/umEEii

Similar unedited Image: https://flic.kr/p/umW83g

It's next to impossible to find an identical photo due to the secrecy amongst us planespotters in involved, in getting exclusive photos.

I have been told lightroom and Photoshop were used to create this effect.

Comment: This looks very much like a duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/156/any-good-tutorials-for-learning-how-to-post-process-images?rq=1 as there's nothing specific to the planespotting community about the processing that's shown here.

Comment: I really casn not identyfy any filter... At the top, are not thoose clouds?

Comment: @Rafael Yes those are clouds

Comment: Please describe the actual colors and filter in the question title, so this looks different from every other question about recreating some _different_ image. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a filter hasn't been used here.

Instead it looks like the photographer gas increased both the colour saturation and contrast of the image. And then to finish it off a vignette has been added.